# Default orientation handling for iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a Universal app (iPhone/iPad) which is very basic. There is a List (UITableView) and Detail (UIWebView).

I am using XCode 4 and have clicked on all 4 orientations in properties.

But when I test it on Simulator and rotate the iPhone/iPad, it does not rotate accordingly.
I wanted to understand is there not a default orientation, which is automatically handled for iPhone/iPad.
I do not want to have any specific things to happen in any particular orientation (so whatever is the defaults would be fine for me)

Comment: I assume the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in your controller returns `YES`, right? It does if you use Apple's code template for a view controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dasblinkenlight said, you must have this line in your view controllers:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

There is not something called default rotation handling, you have to define how it behaves.  Thankfully in practice this is very easy.

Firstly, understand what the auto resize properties do (are you using interface builder?).  You probably want to set the table view and the web view to have autosizing like this to fill the size of the screen when its rotated.

[image]

Another option might be, you want the size to remain constant but to hug the left hand edge .  The best thing to do is play around with the properties to work out what they do.  If there is anything more fancy you need doing, you can set the position of the individual sub views in the method:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```